# How to get specific value from specific key in Python

Tags: python, json

```
jsonA = 
[ {'id': 'xxx1', 'serial': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'model': 'AlertTrace', 'subject': 'EMP004'}, 
{'id': 'xxx2', 'serial': 'XX-WWW-2XSFC', 'model': 'AlertTrace', 'subject': 'EMP005'}, 
{'id': 'xxx3', 'serial': 'VVV-ASD-CDSG', 'model': 'AlertTrace', 'subject': ''} ]
```

I have 3 json data and I want to retrieve data that `subject` is not null. Next, I should able to filter the result that only have two keys which are `serial` and `subject`.

Expected output:

```
jsonA = 
[ {'serial': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject': 'EMP004'}, 
{'serial': 'XX-WWW-2XSFC', 'subject': 'EMP005'} ]
```

I tried with this code: **(but the output only show me the subject only. I need the both value from serial and subject)**

`Filter = [{'serial': dct['serial']} and {'subject': dct['subject']} for dct in jsonA if (dct['subject']) != None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
res = [{'serial': dct['serial'], 'subject': dct['subject']} for dct in jsonA if dct['subject']]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'serial': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject': 'EMP004'}, {'serial': 'XX-WWW-2XSFC', 'subject': 'EMP005'}]
```

In Python the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of `None` and `""` is `False`, so you can use `dct['subject']` directly in conditionals. For creating dictionaries, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: Oh, that mean i need to use `,` instead of `and` ?

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH In this particular case of building a dictionary yes, there other ways but this is the best one

Comment: Alright thanks for correcting me , i will mark this as answer in 11 minutes later.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following example code:

```
a_dict = {'color': 'blue', 'fruit': 'apple', 'pet': 'dog'}
       for key, value in a_dict.items():
            print(key, '->', value)
```

In your code you can try something like:

```
for key, value in jsonA.items():    
   if value != None:
```

return key

But im not completely sure:)